# How do I get a list of all remote branches that I create

Tags: git

The command `git branch -a` produces a list of over 250 branches. I'd like to know which are mine so I can verify they're merged to production and then delete the remotes.

Is there git command to show me all the remote branches I created? This would be easier if all the branches I created were still in my local repo, however I recently got a new computer so my local repo was lost. I don't have the branches locally, nor do I have a complete reflog.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote branches you created"?  A "remote branch" is simply one in `refs/remotes/...` and those are normally created by running `git fetch`.  They exist only so that your repo has a copy of what "they" (the remote) had in its `refs/heads/` ("local" branches) the last time you connected to them and were able to see what they had.

Comment: What I mean is our repo has a lot of remnant branches that have already been merged to master and released to production. We'd like to clean up branches that don't need to exist in the repo any more because they're already out in production. What I'd like to see is a list of the branches in the remotes that I personally created so I can remove them. Obviously there are still many branches in remotes that are being used for development and testing, so I'd like to not touch those.

Comment: Hm, so, you mean "before, when I was on a different computer, I `git push`-ed creating some set of local branches on the server, and others `git push`ed creating other sets of branches, and now my old computer is unavailable but I want to know which server-side local branches *I* created earlier".  Which makes sense, but: git does not record this information itself.  It's possible your server records stuff (e.g., in ssh logs), and if you have enough of those, it might be recoverable that way.

Comment: This is why it's useful to create your branches with information in their names, e.g. I might make a branch named ``wolf/bug-12345``.  I know this is too late for your current situation; but something to remember for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the branches that you created are those for which the last commit was performed by you (is it correct for your case?), here is a small python script I wrote which could solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

remotes_output = subprocess.check_output("git branch -r".split())
remotes = remotes_output.split()[2:]

author_cmd = lambda b: "git log -1 --pretty=format:'%%an' %s" % b
for branch_name in remotes:
    print '%s : %s' % (branch_name, subprocess.check_output(author_cmd(branch_name).split()))
```

It takes the names of the remote branches, removes the first entry which is just the mapping for HEAD and prints out their authors - in the sense written above.

Now, copy this script to a file and grep the output in your shell:

```
python this_script.py | grep 'your name in git'
```

Comment: This gave me a nice big list to sort through. Your assumption is right, that in the majority of cases the branches I created would have me as the last person to commit. Thanks for your suggestion, I think I'll use it.